# From $\langle x, Ay\rangle = \langle Ax, y\rangle$ to $A^* = A$

Tags: functional-analysis

In a complex Hilbert space $V$, if I want to prove that:

\begin{equation}
\forall\,(x, y) \in V,\, \langle x, Ay\rangle = \langle Ax, y\rangle \implies A^* = A
\end{equation}

do I need specific properties to be verified by $A$ ?

Just proving that $A$ behaves similarly to $A^*$ is not enough to prove that they are equal, but I can not find what is missing.

Comment: What is your definition of $A^*$?

Comment: This is just the definiton of a self-adjoint operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition  of the adjoint is 
$$\langle x, A^*y\rangle=\langle Ax, y\rangle\tag{1}$$
If for  all $x$ and $y$, we have $\langle x, Ay\rangle=\langle Ax, y\rangle$, then comparing  with $(1)$, we obtain
$\langle x, A^* y\rangle = \langle x, Ay\rangle$.

Therefore $$\langle x, (A^*-A)y\rangle=0$$
Take $x=(A^*-A)y$, and you'll get that for all $y$, 
$$\|(A^*-A)y\|^2=0$$
In other  words, $$A^*=A$$